# How to retrieve and store both doc.id in a document in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store both the doc.ids in the document location below, so I can reuse them to access the document later. How can I find and store each of them into a variable?

For example: I have to read this document in a function later in the code, so I will store both the doc.ids. Here's the document path: `db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts').doc(random id generated by Firebase)`. How can I store the `uid` and the "random id" in two different variables?

Here's the code snippet which reads every document inside a subcollection and presents it in HTML as an li. So each li is a document, and I need the two doc.ids from every li:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    var query = db.collectionGroup("userPosts")

    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        setupPosts(querySnapshot.docs)
    })

    const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id
        const post = doc.data();
        const picURL = post.picURL;
        let li = `<li class="post">
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            <button class="comment" onclick="comment('${docRefIDpost}')">Comment</button>
            <button class="like" onclick="like('${docRefIDpost}')">Like</button>`;
        
        li += (post.picURL ? `<img class="img" src="${post.picURL}" onclick="openImage('${picURL}')">` : ``);
        li += `</li><br></br>`;
        html += li
    })
    
    posts.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Extra information:

Here's an picture of my database right after I have run the comment function. As you can see, it just creates a new document and do not use the existing document, where the post actually is stored.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKcRp.png)

Here's the comment function as well:

```
function comment(docRefIDpost) {

    var modalcomment = document.getElementById("modal-comment");

    modalcomment.style.display = "block";

    var submitcomment = document.getElementById("submitcomment");

    submitcomment.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        var commentinput = document.getElementById("comment");

        console.log(docRefIDpost)

        db.collection('posts').doc(docRefIDpost).collection('userPosts').doc(docRefIDpost).collection('comments').add({

            comment: commentinput.value,

        })

    })

}
```

Comment: Isn't this already storing the document ID? `var docRefIDpost = docRef.id`

Comment: It stores the first of them, but not the second one

Comment: Frank, do you know how to store both doc.ids? Because the var docRefIDpost .... only stores the first one (the uid) not the document id in the subcollection userPosts.

Answer (score 0):

To also have the document ID of the `userPosts` in your HTML, you'll get them from `doc`:

```
const setupPosts = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const docRefIDPost = doc.id;
        const post = doc.data();
        const picURL = post.picURL;
        let li = `<li class="post">
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            <button class="comment" onclick="comment('${docRefIDpost}')">Comment</button>
            <button class="like" onclick="like('${docRefIDpost}')">Like</button>`;
        
        li += (post.picURL ? `<img class="img" src="${post.picURL}" onclick="openImage('${picURL}')">` : ``);
        li += `</li><br></br>`;
        html += li
    })
    
    posts.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Now it only uses the last doc.id. The code makes a new document with a new subcollection 'userPosts' and then makes a new empty document and makes the comments inside that empty document. It does not use the existing document.

Comment: Each `<button class="comment" onclick="comment('${docRefIDpost}')">` should have the ID of the post it is for. Is that not what you're seeing? If not, can you set up a reproduction on a site like jsbin/stackblitz, so that we're all looking at the same thing?

Comment: Neither jsbin or stackblitz didn't work. Maybe it only was me doing something wrong, but I added some new information. Hope this helps